# How to debug ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms?

Tags: sql, oracle, synonym

I'm familiar with the issue behind ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms, but is there any trick to debugging it, or do I just have to "create or replace" my way out of it?

Is there a way to query the schema or whatever to find out what the current definition of a public synonym is?

Even more awesome would be a graphical tool, but at this point, anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem wasn't actually a looping chain of synonyms, but the fact that the synonym was pointing to a view that did not exist.

Oracle apparently errors out as a looping chain in this condition.

Comment: Well, something more must have been going on.  If I create a view, create a synonym for it, then drop the view, when I try to query the synonym I get:  ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid.

Comment: The tables that the view was pulling from are all tables with public synonyms as well.  That may have had something to do with it.

Comment: I received this same error for a public synonym pointing to a table that no longer existed.

Comment: I'm trying to insert into newly created table and im getting same error, no  clue why :(

Comment: I find it interesting how useful this answer is... for me, I was referring to a nonexistent type when re-adding a procedure to a package. After adding the type back in, the error went away.

Comment: A missing object can create a chain by virtue of being missing

Comment: Oracle and their ever helpful error messages, this was exactly my problem I misstyped the tablename while creating my synonym, I wonder why Oracle allowed me to create the synonym to a non existant object, should have compile it and throw a table or view exception and not create the synonym but wherever.

Answer (score 33):

If you are using TOAD, go to View>Toad Options>Oracle>General and remove TOAD_PLAN_TABLE from EXPLAIN PLAN section and put PLAN_TABLE

Comment: Or even better, use `sys.plan_table$`.

Answer (score 23):

The data dictionary table `DBA_SYNONYMS` has information about all the synonyms in a database.  So you can run the query

```
SELECT table_owner, table_name, db_link
  FROM dba_synonyms 
 WHERE owner        = 'PUBLIC'
   AND synonym_name = <<synonym name>>
```

to see what the public synonym currently points at.

Comment: AND synonym_name LIKE '%synonym name%' -- a bit more helpful.

Comment: If you do not have access to dba_synonyms you can try same query on all_synonyms

Answer (score 20):

The less intuitive solution to this error code seems to be problems with the objects that the synonym is pointing to.

Here is my SQL for finding synonyms that point to erroneous objects.

```
SELECT S.OWNER as SYN_OWNER, S.SYNONYM_NAME as SYN_NAME,
    S.TABLE_OWNER as OBJ_OWNER, S.TABLE_NAME as OBJ_NAME,
    CASE WHEN O.OWNER is null THEN 'MISSING' ELSE O.STATUS END as OBJ_STATUS
FROM DBA_SYNONYMS S
    LEFT JOIN DBA_OBJECTS O ON S.TABLE_OWNER = O.OWNER AND S.TABLE_NAME = O.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE O.OWNER is null
    OR O.STATUS != 'VALID';
```

Comment: The best answer. A way to figure out what is broken.

Comment: @Jarrod Chesney what to do with the results from this query ?

Comment: @Daniel Belém Duarte recreate the missing object, then recompile.  Worked for me. Great piece of code.

Comment: This solved mine; interestingly the Synonym doesn't look like it's invalid when looking in Oracle SQL Developer, but sure enough the synonym had been created using the wrong owner.

Answer (score 6):

Try this select to find the problematic synonyms, it lists all synonyms that are pointing to an object that does not exist (tables,views,sequences,packages, procedures, functions)

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_synonyms
WHERE table_owner = 'USER'
    AND (
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM dba_tables
            WHERE dba_synonyms.table_name = dba_tables.TABLE_NAME
            )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM dba_views
            WHERE dba_synonyms.table_name = dba_views.VIEW_NAME
            )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM dba_sequences
            WHERE dba_synonyms.table_name = dba_sequences.sequence_NAME
            )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM dba_dependencies
            WHERE type IN (
                    'PACKAGE'
                    ,'PROCEDURE'
                    ,'FUNCTION'
                    )
                AND dba_synonyms.table_name = dba_dependencies.NAME
            )
        )
```

Comment: This only works for a specific schema and for specific kinds of object. It would work better if it referenced dba_objects.

Comment: I would recommand chaning the last condition for :

`AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM all_objects
            WHERE object_type NOT IN (
                    'SYNONYM'
                    )
                AND dba_synonyms.table_name = all_objects.OBJECT_NAME
            )`

Answer (score 3):

Today I got this error, and after debugging I figured out that the actual tables were misssing, which I was referring using synonyms. So I suggest - first check that whether the tables exists!! :-))

Comment: In my case the "missing" table was just owned by a different DB user. All sorts of variations on this theme!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1) See what Objects exist with the name:

```
select * from all_objects where object_name = upper('&object_name');
```

It could be that a Synonym exists but no Table?

---

Step 2) If that's not the problem, investigate the Synonym:

```
select * from all_synonyms where synonym_name = upper('&synonym_name');
```

It could be that an underlying Table or View to that Synonym is missing?

Comment: without creating a table I created the public synonym,since this table needs to be accessed from another schema, i executed the grant which was not working. i tried the select * from so_and_so_table; the query returned >"ORA-01775 looping chain of synonyms". After creating the table this issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A developer accidentally wrote code that generated and ran the following SQL statement `CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM "DUAL" FOR "DUAL";` which caused `select * from dba_synonyms where table_name = 'DUAL';`
 to return `PUBLIC DUAL    SOME_USER   DUAL` rather than `PUBLIC   DUAL    SYS DUAL`.

We were able to fix it (thanks to [How to recreate public synonym "DUAL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504918/how-to-recreate-public-synonym-dual)) by running

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_SYSTEM_TRIG_ENABLED"=FALSE SCOPE=MEMORY;
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM DUAL FOR SYS.DUAL;
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_SYSTEM_TRIG_ENABLED"=true SCOPE=MEMORY;
```

Answer (score 2):

While Jarrod's answer is a good idea, and catches a broader range of related problems, I found this query found in Oracle forums to more directly address the (originally stated) issue:

```
select owner, synonym_name, connect_by_iscycle CYCLE
from dba_synonyms
where connect_by_iscycle > 0
connect by nocycle prior table_name = synonym_name
and prior table_owner = owner
union
select 'PUBLIC', synonym_name, 1
from dba_synonyms
where owner = 'PUBLIC'
and table_name = synonym_name
and (table_name, table_owner) not in (select object_name, owner from dba_objects
where object_type != 'SYNONYM')
```

https://community.oracle.com/message/4176300#4176300

You will not have to wade through other kinds of invalid objects. Just those that are actually in endless loops.

Comment: You should also ensure that the column DBA_SYNONYMS.DB_LINK is NULL or points to your own database.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which turned out to be caused by missing double quotes off the table and schema name.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same ORA-01775 error but in our case, the schema user was missing some 'grant select' on a couple of the public synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this error today. 
This is how we debugged and fixed it.

1. Package went to invalid state due to this error `ORA-01775`.
2. With the error line number , We went thru the `package` body code and found the code which was trying to insert data into a `table`.
3. We ran below queries to check if the above `table` and `synonym` exists.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '&TABLE_NAME';  -- No rows returned

   SELECT * FROM DBA_SYNONYMS WHERE SYNONYM_NAME = '&SYNONYM_NAME'; -- 1 row returned
   ```
4. With this we concluded that the table needs to be re- created. As the `synonym` was pointing to a `table` that did not exist.
5. DBA team re-created the table and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
I faced the above error while I was trying to compile a Package which was using an object for which synonym was created however underlying object was not available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following sql to find entries in all_synonyms where there is no corresponding object for the object_name (in user_objects):

```
 select * 
   from all_synonyms 
   where table_owner = 'SCOTT' 
     and synonym_name not like '%/%'
     and table_name not in (
       select object_name from user_objects
         where object_type in (
           'TABLE', 'VIEW', 'PACKAGE', 'SEQUENCE',
           'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'TYPE'
         )
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

http://ora-01775.ora-code.com/ suggests:

**ORA-01775**:  looping chain of synonyms
*Cause*:    Through a series of CREATE synonym statements, a synonym was defined that referred to itself. For example, the following definitions are circular:
`CREATE SYNONYM s1 for s2 CREATE SYNONYM s2 for s3 CREATE SYNONYM s3 for s1`
*Action*:   Change one synonym definition so that it applies to a base table or view and retry the operation.

Comment: -1 The OP understands what a looping chain is. What the question asks for is a method to identify which synonyms are broken.

Comment: @KshitizSharma - apparently you didn't read either the OP or my answer, a quote from Ora-code.com. The "*Action*" from the quote should have answered his question. And since no one in the last 8 years has felt the need to say it was wrong, your down vote was not especially helpful. Do you have a better answer? If not, and given the near-decade-old question and answer herein, I'd appreciate a reversal of your down vote.

Comment: The OP has asked for a way to query the schema for finding invalid synonyms or graphical tool to locate and fix. The advice to fix it yourself by modifying synonym definition doesn't count as a debugging trick. The age of it, or my lack of a solution have nothing to do with the quality of this one.

Answer (score -1):

If you are compiling a PROCEDURE, possibly this is referring to a table or view that does not exist as it is created in the same PROCEDURE. In this case the solution is to make the query declared as String eg `v_query: = 'insert into table select * from table2` and then execute immediate on `v_query`;

This is because the compiler does not yet recognize the object and therefore does not find the reference. Greetings.

Answer (score -1):

I had a function defined in the wrong schema and without a public synonym. I.e. my proc was in schema "Dogs" and the function was in schema "Cats". The function didn't have a public synonym on it to allow Dogs to access the cats' function.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the table name and the synonym both existed but under different owner names. I re-created the tables under the owner name that matched the owner name in synonyms.

I used the queries posted by @Mahi_0707