# Oracle Synonym Error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am knew to programming against an Oracle DB and I am getting this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9: PL/SQL: ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

Is this something wrong in my code or in my DB? The code is the same for pretty much the whole data access layer and I am only getting this error when I try to insert into one particular table.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE DEAL_NOTE 
SET NOTE_TXT=:prmNOTE_TXT 
WHERE DEAL_ID=:prmDEAL_ID;

IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
INSERT INTO DEAL_NOTE (NOTE_TXT, DEAL_ID) values (:prmNOTE_TXT, :prmDEAL_ID);
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: This is most likely an error in your SQL. Perhaps you could edit your post to include your SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in your database.

The ORA-01775 error indicates that you have one synonym A that references another synonym B.  Synonym B, in turn, references synonym A.  Something like

```
SQL> create synonym foo2 for foo1;

Synonym created.

SQL> create synonym foo1 for foo2;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from foo2;
select * from foo2
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

The only way to correct this is to fix the synonyms in the database so that you don't have these sorts of circular dependencies.  You can run a query to identify these synonym loops (assuming you just have a one-level loop where A points to B and B points to A rather than more involved cycles) with a query like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select a.synonym_name, b.synonym_name
  2    from all_synonyms a,
  3         all_synonyms b
  4   where a.owner = b.table_owner
  5     and a.synonym_name = b.table_name
  6     and b.owner = a.table_owner
  7*    and b.synonym_name = a.table_name
SQL> /

SYNONYM_NAME                   SYNONYM_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
FOO2                           FOO1
FOO1                           FOO2
```

Comment: When I run that query I do not get any results, does this mean that I have an even larger problem?

Comment: @esastincy - It likely means that you have more than a one-level cycle-- synonym A points to synonym B, B points to C, and C points to A.  It's probably easier just to manually walk through the dependency tree-- see what the synonym you're using references in `ALL_SYNONYMS`, see what that synonym references, etc. until you find the cycle.

Comment: You can also get this error if you create a synonym that references itself. This easily happens when you create a PUBLIC synonym for a particular schema's table/view, then drop/rename the table/view.

Comment: @DCookie - How do you get an ORA-01775 by dropping a table that a synonym references?  I can only get an ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error in that case.

Comment: @Justin: create a table me.x. create a PUBLIC SYNONYM x FOR me.x. Drop the TABLE me.x. SELECT * FROM x; results the error. You really don't need the CREATE/DROP the table steps, either, it just illustrates how I've usually seen it happen. Just create a PUBLIC SYNONYM x for me.x. SELECT * FROM x. Same error.

Comment: I get the ORA-00942 error in that case, not ORA-01775.  
create public synonym enp2_syn for scott.emp2;
drop table emp2;
select * from emp2_syn;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @JustinCave let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1520/discussion-between-dcookie-and-justin-cave)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a code problem - probably something to do with what you have on line2 of your script.

Care to post it?

From this post [How to debug ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247090/how-to-debug-ora-01775-looping-chain-of-synonyms)

http://ora-01775.ora-code.com/ suggests:

**ORA-01775:** looping chain of synonyms
Cause: Through a series of CREATE synonym statements, a synonym was defined that referred to itself. For example, the following definitions are circular:

```
CREATE SYNONYM s1 for s2 CREATE SYNONYM s2 for s3 CREATE SYNONYM s3 for s1
```

Action: Change one synonym definition so that it applies to a base table or view and retry the operation.

Comment: It's unlikely that the problem is related to the script.  Line 2 column 9 is undoubtedly where the reference to the synonym occurs.  The problem is the underlying definition of the synonym.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in the DB -- probably the table you are touching is a synonym that indirectly references itself.