# Why Oracle is complaining about a looping chain of synonyms (ORA01775) in package compilation?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I really need to understand why the behavior below is happening.

First, I just create a synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM SYN_NAME FOR MY_TABE@MY_DBLINK;
```

Second, when I try to select the rows from the table, the following error appears:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

*Great, the table really does not exist.*

**However** when I try to compile a Package that is using the synonym above, the compilation error is:

```
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

There are no synonyms with the same name, cycling synonyms or database link/synonym conflicts in the entire database. Of course that when I create the table in the target database link schema, the errors runaway.

Could some one explain me why the errors aren't the same?

Comment: Does this apply?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247090/how-to-debug-ora-01775-looping-chain-of-synonyms

Comment: Not really. I have been looking for answers before my post and I considered the one that you pointed out.

Comment: The error is indicitive of not having permissions to do the select.  The @my_DBLINK; accesses the remote database using it's own credentials.  If that user doesn't have the proper permissions, it wouldn't be able to access the table, thus no table/view error and looping chain error.  I think if you query all_objects using the userID on the link, if you don't see the table, that would likely be the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, but both errors should be the same, when I compile the package or when I just run a select statement. For me the ORA01775 does not make sense. My question is just the reason that the errors are not the same.

Comment: I'd have to defer to AskTom or similar oracle support for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating to the Oracle Database 12c version, the error changed back to:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

If someone is experiencing that kind of exception, the answer is that it could be the synonym target missing and don't a loop synonym.

I hope it helps someone.