# ORA-01775: Cyclic string of synonyms

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have to import a table from an Oracle server to a MS SQL server. Therefor I have created a linked server (Linked_server_new) which is connected from the SQL server to the Oracle server trough a datasource (defined in a TNSNAMES.ora). The test of the connection was successfull.

my SQL statement:

```
SELECT * INTO SQL_table FROM OPENQUERY(Linked_server_new, 
'SELECT * FROM Oracle_table')
```

after this I've got following error message:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "Linked_server_new" returned message "ORA-01775: Cyclic string of synonyms
".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM Oracletabelle" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "APC_Verbindungsserver_neu".
```

I would be really happy if somebody has an idea.

Comment: You have a circular definition of synonyms somehow.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247090/how-to-debug-ora-01775-looping-chain-of-synonyms

Comment: This message pops up in some general cases when there is just something wrong with synonym, not necessarily a cycle.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your support. The problem was that the tables wasn't in the database.